# react input type image onclick attribute is not rendered not clickable as well

Tags: reactjs

Hope all are doing good. Apologies this is repeated or seems silly.
I have a functional styled component to render a input type image called `LinkedInInput.jsx`.

```
const LinkedInInput = styled.input`
  left: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 7%;
  height: 6%;
  font-size: 2.4vw;

  background:url(${(props) => props.src});
  @media (orientation: portrait) {
    top: 10%;
    left: 19%;
    height: 6%;
    position: absolute;
  }
`;
```

This component getting rendered from the `index.jsx` like below:

````
```<LinkedInInput src={linkedInURL} type="image" onclick={linkedInLink}></LinkedInInput```
````

When this component rendered on webpage, I'm not able to see the onclick attribute on the input type and that is not clickable as well. Can you please tell me how to make sure that this component is clickable and opens the link.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try changing onclick to onClick.

refer this.

https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/07/styled-components-react/

Comment: perfect I am able to solve this 
```<LinkedInInput src={linkedInURL} type="image" onClick={()=>{window.location=linkedInLink}}></LinkedInInput>```

Comment: Happy to help. :)
Would you mind accepting answer?